# DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \D

Tags: python

I got a warning regarding depreciation of `\D`, how can I update my code? (bellow) to remove the warning?

```
re.sub("\D", "", value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with

```
str(value).translate(str.maketrans("", "", string.punctuation))
```